# Tfs project have red x on it and can't expand to work items, source etc. on one machine

Tags: tfs

I have a user that is trying to access a team project that he has been working with (in).

He has 2 computers, on 1 he can access it, on the other he can't (project has red x).  And actually he can access any projects on that machine, all have the same red X.

He was been able to accesses the project on both machines last week.  And I have no idea what could have changed.

Searching the web found a # of post regarding folder within a project with a red X but not much on a project itself.  But we tried these 2 links ...did not help

- [visualstudiomagazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/08/02/the-red-x-of-death.aspx)
- [social.msdn.microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/tfsgeneral/thread/0e7c2b24-976e-425c-a8ea-56f4afda4812%20devenv.exe%20/ResetSettings)

Also tried re-installing Team Explorer & installed SP 1 (it was not on the machine).

Any ideas where to start looking?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install TFS 2010 SP1? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2182621

Comment: I would have to look but he is the only one seeing this issue, and we have 20+ developers using this TFS instance.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Red X' problem can be from many different causes.

However, seeing as the user is experiencing the problem on one machine, and not on the other means that it's unlikely to be a server-side issue.

On the computer that is having the problem:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Close any other applications that could be using the TFS Object Model
3. Open and delete the contents of the following folder: `%localappdata%\microsoft\Team Foundation`. On Win7, this will typically expand to something like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation`
4. Start Visual Studio again and connect to TFS

TFS clients have a local cache of metadata. There are situations where this metadata can get corrupted. Therefore, deleting it will force a fresh download of the metadata and resolve the Red X issue.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling tracing on the [client](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhintz/archive/2007/03/30/tfs-client-tracing.aspx) and/or [TFS server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bryang/archive/2011/11/14/tracing-in-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx) should allow you to track down the error.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after installing .NET 1.1, Visual Studio 2003, Active Reports 2.0 and Dundas Charts on 64-bit Win 7. None of the other fixes worked for me, but I resolved my issues (which also included weird IE behavior) after running the **ie8-rereg.32-on-64.cmd** script found here: http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=42&id=133&artlang=en.